# Showing that field embedding exists

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Q. Let $F$ be a field and $f(x) \in F[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $> 0$ over $F$. Show that there is a field $F'$ and an embedding $q:F \to F'$ such that the polynomial $f^q$ has a root in $F'$ where $f^q$ is obtained by replacing each coefficient $a$ of $f$ by $q(a)$.

My attempt: By Kronecker's theorem, there exists a field extension $F'/F$ in which $f(x) \in F[x]$ has a root.

My question: How do I go from here to prove that an field embedding $q$ exists? My guess is that existence of a field extension implies that an embedding should also exist but I'm not sure about it. I also don't see this mentioned anywhere in the definition of a field extension: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension)

Comment: If $f$ is irreducible over $F$, then you can take $F'$ to be $F[x]/I$ where $I$ is the ideal generated by $f$, and $q(a)=a+I$. If $f$ is not irreducible, you get to work a little harder.

Comment: Thanks, now I see that $q(a) = a+I$ can be the embedding for irreducible case.

Comment: For the reducible case, we can use the fact that it can be broken down into a product of irreducibles (as $F[x]$ = Euclidean domain so UFD as well). Then, pick any irreducible and follow the same argument as you said. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes, you've got it. Let me encourage you to write up what you now know, and to post it as an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since, degree of $f(x)>0$, there are only two cases ($f(x)$ cannot be a unit):

(a) $f(x)$ is irreducible

For this case, using Kronecker's theorem we can say that there exists a field extension $F'=F[x]/<f(x)>$ where $f(x)$ has a root. And the mapping given by $q:F \to F'$ where $q(a) = a + <f(x)>$ for $a \in F$ is an injective homomorphism and hence an embedding.

(b) $f(x)$ is reducible

Since $F$ is a field, $F[x]$ is an euclidean domain and therefore a UFD. This implies there exist a product of irreducible polynomials (uniquely up to order and units) for $f(x)$. Let $g(x)$ be any such irreducible polynomial. Then, because any root of $g(x)$ is also a root of $f(x)$ we can apply the same method as in (a) to get an embedding $q(a)=a+<g(x)>$.

Comment: Good, except defining $q:F\to F'$ it doesn't make sense to talk about $q(g(x))$ since $g(x)$ isn't in $F$.

Comment: Nice catch, I've fixed it now.